# subir una imagen con SwiftUI y Alamofire

Tags: php, swift, alamofire

Estoy con una app y quiero hacer una foto y subirla a un servidor, estoy probando con esta función pero se crea un fichero con 0 bytes, la conexión se produce, ya que llegan datos, pero la imagen no llega.¿donde puede estar el error?

Aquí el código en SwiftUI

```
func saveImgCV(img: UIImage)
       {
       guard let url = URL(string: "https://miurl.es/upload-movil.php") 
        else {
            return
        }
        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
          
    let name = "profile-urbian.jpg"
    AF.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
        if let imgData  = img.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.8){
            multipartFormData.append(imgData, withName: "foto", fileName: name, mimeType: "image/jpeg")
        }
        multipartFormData.append(name.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: "nombre")
    }, to: url, method: .post).response { response in
        if let data = response.data
        {
            print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? "")
        }else{
            print("sometring went wrong")
        }
    }
}
```

Aquí el código que recibe en PHP

```
<?php
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
        $imagen= $_POST['foto'];
        $nombre= $_POST['nombre'];
        $path = "uploads/foto.png";
        file_put_contents($path,base64_decode($imagen));
        echo "Subio imagen Correctamente";
    }else{
        echo "Error";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar detalles sobre el problema, explica si aparecen errores en la consola (y cuáles), así como lo que pasa en PHP y lo que debería pasar.

Comment: Gracias, es la primera vez, ya he dejado una explicación.

Comment: Qué valor envías en `(img: UIImage)`? La imagen la tienes en los `assets`? Qué te imprime `$imagen` en el php?

Comment: En `(img: UIImage)`  le envio una imagen realizada por la cámara, también he probado con una imagen de los àssets`pero nada, al final crea un fichero en el servidor pero de 0bytes.   @Bicho